# How to open an xml file on google earth using a shell command

Tags: command-line, bash, python, google-earth, xml

I have embedded a shell script within a python script to open a xml file with google earth. But google earth throws an error saying it can't read the file but, i am able to open it manually with google earth.

This is the command I used

```
import os
os.system("sudo /opt/google/earth/free/google-earth /home/krithin/Downloads/qwe.KML")
```

I am quite new to Linux.
I am running this on a VM with Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I suppose your $HOME is `/home/krithin/`; so why would you use `sudo`?

Comment: That's cause OP is calling `/opt/google/earth/free/google-earth` which won't work without `sudo` @ridgy

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative way to call upon google-earth that worked. There is a package in python called subprocess that can be used to call an external program, so i used that instead.